# Assistance with adding files to source control

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I have set up a server to handle my source control with Visual Svn Server. I have created a repository with the normal folder layout of trunk, tags, branches. All good so far.

On my local pc I have replicated the folder structure of trunk, tags and branches. Within the trunk and branches folders I have a Visual Studio solution in each along with some other files such as a word doc which is not part of the visual studio solution.

I am using Ankhsvn add in for visual studio and also tortoisesvn.

I want to Ankhsvn to check in/out files etc for visual studio and tortoisesvn for the other files.

I am wondering how I add the local files to my subversion repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself the trouble with Ankh and install [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).
If you want to add a file it's a simple `right-click > TortoiseSVN > Add`.

Your question has also been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984994/ankhsvn-doesnt-add-files-to-svn)

Comment: It sucks when someone's answer on how to do something is, don't do it and instead do something else, but truly Brock is right here.

Comment: @Brad: Yeah I know i normally hate those answers too, but I've used a Ankh before and it's horrible. You can't go past Tortoise on Windows IMHO

Comment: Can I add the files with TortoiseSVN at the start and then use Ankh from there on to check in and check out files while working on .net projects?

Answer (score 0):

With AnkhSVN, first make sure your project is in a common directory, the "Add to Subversion" feature doesn't support multi working copy solutions yet (the rest of AnkhSVN supports this just fine).

Right click the solution file, and choose "Add solution to Subversion". In the dialog that comes up. Fill out the dialog as described in the [help](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/wiki/dialogs/Ankh.UI.SccManagement.AddToSubversion) section that comes up when you hit the `?` button.

Also see "[Add a solution to Subversion](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_add_soln.html)" from the AnkhSVN documentation.

When AnkhSVN is managing the files in the solution, you can use TortoiseSVN or any other tool to manage the files that need to be in Subversion but aren't part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You say 'replicated the folder structure'. I'm assuming you didn't 'check out' the structure you have in the repository? Open the repo-browser, and checkout the structure. Now put your files into the new set of folders, because these have .svn subfolders you can now add them to the repository with ank or tortoise svn.

Forgive bad formatting, typing on iphone